# For LOOP taking time to execute in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, time-complexity

I am taking a demo test at codility.com.

I tried the following PHP test code:

```
function solution($A) {
    $min = 0;
    $size = count($A)-1;
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
        if($i=0)
            $min=$A[0];
    }
    return $min;
}
```

The script takes around 3.03s to execute where they have set the maximum execution time to 2.00s.

And if i comment the FOR LOOP it works properly.

Any idea ?

Comment: `$i=0` is probably the issue.

Comment: Remove `$size = count($A)-1;` as you are not using it and change `if($i=0)` to `if($i==0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwritting your $i variable here:

```
if($i=0)
```

it should be

```
if($i==0)
```

Answer (score 1):

because you have wirte `if($i=0)` it is assignment operator not comparision operator. make it correct `if($i==0)`

```
function solution($A) {
    $min = 0;
    $size = count($A)-1;
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
        if($i==0)
            $min=$A[0];
    }
    return $min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop looks like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
```

This means: initialize $i to 0, and until $i is 5 or more, execute the loop and increment $i.

But, you wrote this:

```
if($i = 0)
```

To compare $i and 0, you should've used `==`, not `=`. This sets $i to 0. The if is not executed, as 0 is equal to false. Then $i is incremented to 1. 1 is less than 5, so the loop is executed forever.

Use `if($i == 0)` to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake that everyone has pointed out which is `if($i=0)` should be `if($i==0)`.

But I have one concern. Why there is a for loop when it is simply returning `$min` which is `$A[0]` ?